# Generate an array of javascript functions from a for loop

Tags: javascript

I am having some issues with an array of functions. When I run the code below it adds the function to the array but it doesnt change the value of index inside the function. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
var dlinks = [];
function getLinks(index) {
    return function() {
        this.echo('report link September');
        casper.start(reportList[index]);
        casper.thenOpen(reportList[index], function() {
            casper.capture('data1.png');
            var dlUrl = reportList[index] + '&csv=true';
            this.download(dlUrl , reportDates[index].substring(0,2) + myfile, "GET");
        });
    }
}
console.log(getLinks(1));
for (var i = 0; i < reportList.length; i ++) {
        dlinks.push(getLinks(i));
}
```

Comment: What behaviour makes you think so?  It looks okay to me.  Have you printed the actual index?

Comment: Yes the console.log(getLinks(1)): prints the function but it the variable index remains unchanged. It should be 1. The reason is I dont actually call the functions until after the dlinks array has been generated.

Comment: But have you done a console.log("Index is "+index) in the generated functions when you call them later (through dlinks).

Comment: Wow you are right I was going just of console log. Sorry for wasting your time! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have some slight syntax errors.

```
var dlinks = [];
function getLinks(index) {
    return function() {
        return index;
    };
}
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    dlinks.push(getLinks(i));
    $("body").append(getLinks(i));
}

$("body").append("Test");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HFXrm/